# How to loop through the keys of each object in a knockout observableArray and create table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` that is populated by dynamic sql data. So the columns returned could be different at any time.

I want to display the SQL results in a HTML table. However, the below is not working.

This is how I want the output to look...

[image]

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables   
    self.taskRecordOverview = ko.observableArray([
    {
        "Entity": "DEMO",
        "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Level": "Level 3",
        "Addendum Errors": null,
        "Cash Process": "Created",
        "Corporate Actions": null,
        "Expenses": null
    },
    {
        "Entity": "DEMO",
        "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Level": "Level 5",
        "Addendum Errors": "Created",
        "Cash Process": "Created",
        "Corporate Actions": "Created",
        "Expenses": "Created"
    },
    {
        "Entity": "SP00",
        "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
        "Level": "Level 5",
        "Addendum Errors": "Created",
        "Cash Process": "Approved",
        "Corporate Actions": "Created",
        "Expenses": "Created"
    }
]); 
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>??</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: taskRecordOverview">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f79r4h2g/

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `foreach` loop for `taskRecordOverview`, you need to loop through the `keys` of each object and display the value. You can do so with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Working snippet:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.taskRecordOverview = ko.observableArray([{
      "Entity": "DEMO",
      "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
      "Level": "Level 3",
      "Addendum Errors": null,
      "Cash Process": "Created",
      "Corporate Actions": null,
      "Expenses": null
    },
    {
      "Entity": "DEMO",
      "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
      "Level": "Level 5",
      "Addendum Errors": "Created",
      "Cash Process": "Created",
      "Corporate Actions": "Created",
      "Expenses": "Created"
    },
    {
      "Entity": "SP00",
      "Period": "2017-07-31T00:00:00",
      "Level": "Level 5",
      "Addendum Errors": "Created",
      "Cash Process": "Approved",
      "Corporate Actions": "Created",
      "Expenses": "Created"
    }
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <!--Only one object is enough for header-->
    <tr data-bind="foreach:Object.keys(taskRecordOverview()[0]),visible:taskRecordOverview().length > 0">
      <th data-bind="text:$data"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: taskRecordOverview">
    <!--Get the keys in each object and loop through them-->
    <tr data-bind="foreach: Object.keys($data)">
      <!--Get the "value" for a key-->
      <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f79r4h2g/3/)**

---

If the nested `$data` and `$parent` [binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) are confusing then we can [alias foreach items using **`as`**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items) to make it more clear:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data:taskRecordOverview, as: '_task'}">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: { data:Object.keys(_task), as: '_key'}">
      <td data-bind="text: _task[_key]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Here's an updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f79r4h2g/2/)

I know this is an old question, but it is an interesting one and the answer will hopefully help someone else in the future :)